# Yii2 Exception: ApcCache requires PHP apc extension to be loaded

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, php-extension

I receive the exception when configure the cache components in main configuration of advanced-template frontend, on my php.ini the extension rsults enabled, how I can fix this problem?
frontend/config/main.php:

```
'cache' => [
    'class' => 'yii\caching\ApcCache',
    'keyPrefix' => 'myapp',       // a unique cache key prefix
],
```

The `phpinfo()` about apcu:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Solved by updating the configuration as follow:

```
'cache' => [
    'class' => 'yii\caching\ApcCache',
    'keyPrefix' => 'myapp',       // a unique cache key prefix
    'useApcu' => true,
],
```

The php version is the 7.0.18 and, as I can learn, this version use only apcu and not the apc like php 5.X

Comment: `'useApcu' => true,` worked form me on MAMP Pro with php 7.2.3

Comment: Worked fine.
After changing from FileCache to ApcCache, Ialso  had to close the browser and reopen the link again.

Answer (score 1):

[APC](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) and [APCu](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php) are diffrent extensions. To make it work, you have to install `APC`, in linux:

```
sudo apt-get install php-apc
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Yupik, the problem was not the extension installation but the Yii2 main configurations, by default Yii2 use apc but, as my answer, php 7 use apcu and this have to be declared explicitly, the [component class](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/caching/ApcCache.php) is enough clear

Comment: Well, you didn't provided PHP version in question. For PHP7 `'useApcu'` param will fix this problem as you said.

Answer (score 0):

[This fix](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/16970) worked for me.
The only fix that worked is to explicitly change

```
public $useApcu = false;
```

in the ApcCache class to

```
public $useApcu = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed

```
sudo apt-get install phpX-apc
```

and restart your web-server, Where X is your PHP version running in your Debian PC, Example for PHP 8.2

```
sudo apt-get install php8.2-apc
```